# New line in a4j:commandbutton value is removed after reRender'ed

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

:) Hi all, this is my first post after searching through the forum for similar posts

I have buttons that look like this:
http://img.villagephotos.com/p/2006-10/1223248/pc3.JPG **(Sorry but it said that new user needs 10 reputation to post images and more than one link)**

and here is the code of the button:

```
<a4j:commandButton styleClass="pcPopUpButton" ajaxSingle="true" eventsQueue="myQueue" value="#{_pcs.priceKey}&#10;Tx Price: $#{_pcs.amount} + Tx Fee: $#{_pcs.fee}&#10;= $#{_pcs.amount+_pcs.fee}"/>
```

The problem is there when i reRender the buttons using ajax reRender, the buttons become like what is shown in the picture.

I checked the page code using firebug (first load):

```
    <input type="button" value="ADULT
Tx Price: $5.00 + Tx Fee: $5.00
= $10.00" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('tblBooking:repeater:0:pcLink','tblBooking',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4','parameters':{'ajaxSingle':'tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4','tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4':'tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4'} ,'eventsQueue':'myQueue','actionUrl':'/quebecTicketing/TblBookingEdit.seam'} );return false;" name="tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4" id="tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4" class="pcPopUpButton">
```

(after reRender'ed) :

```
<input type="button" class="pcPopUpButton" id="tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4" name="tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('tblBooking:repeater:0:pcLink','tblBooking',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4','parameters':{'ajaxSingle':'tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4','tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4':'tblBooking:repeater:0:pcGrid2:0:pc4'} ,'eventsQueue':'myQueue','actionUrl':'/quebecTicketing/TblBookingEdit.seam'} );return false;" value="ADULT Tx Price: $5.00 + Tx Fee: $5.00 = $10.00">
```

If I use h:commandButton to submit the whole page, the buttons still remain the same but I can't use h:commandButton because there are some validation in the page.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with validation? You can still validate with h:commandButton.

Comment: Anyay, what you want is to have your "value" with line breaks, right? I guess that the "&#10;" does that, right?

Comment: oops, sorry my mistake I meant I wanted to avoid some field validation using ajaxSingle="true"
and ya the &#10; line breaks for the first page load but after reRender'ed it's not working.

Comment: Don't know if this will work or not, but I would try not using the value attribute:
<h:commandLink >
  #{_pcs.priceKey}<br/>
  Tx Price: $#{_pcs.amount} + Tx Fee $#{_pcs.fee}<br/>
  =$#{_pcs.amount+_pcs.fee}
</h:commandLink>

Comment: Hmm I guess so, but I have to use a button as shown in the picture link. :(

Comment: Any suggestion or guide anyone please :)  ?

Comment: Sorry, missed the part about it being an a4j button.  Just replace <h:commandLink >  with <a4j:commandLink>.  You can style your links to look like buttons.

Comment: Thanks! look like that s the only way to overcome it, I ll give it a try in few days :)

Comment: Hmm the <br/> worked for the link all the time. But in order to call bean action, user has to click on the exact link.
I couldnt manage to call the bean action from javascript onclick function (if user click on the td space that contain the link)
Any precious sharing for me pls ? O_o

Comment: how do you rerender the buttons? do you rerender the whole form?
i have seen weird effects when just a part of the form is reRendered... (think it was issues when adding/removing elements dynamically though).

Comment: Hi, the button is wrapped inside a rich:dataTable and I reRender the dataTable.  btw In the end we chose to reduce the text in the button and display all the text in 1 line = =||